# Child Class argument not being accepted by Super Abstract Class Parent

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, arguments

Total newbie here (thanks for bearing with). I created an abstract parent class:

```
public abstract class Account {


public double setInterestRate (double interestRate) {

    return this. interestRate = interestRate / 100;


public abstract void withdraw(double amount);


public void deposit(double amount) {
    if (amount < 0) { // amount is invalid: exception occurs
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Deposit cannot be a"
            + " negative value.");
    } else {
    this.deposit = amount;  
    balance = balance + amount;

    }
}

public void calculateBalance () {

        double interestTotal = balance * setInterestRate(interestRate);
        this.balance = balance + interestTotal;

}    
public double annualEarnings (double interest) {

  return this.interest =  1000 * setInterestRate(interestRate);
```

}

In the child class I want to pass the annualInterest variable as an argument to super.annualEarnings(annualInterest) method I call in the toString():

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account implements Overdraftable {

protected double annualInterest = 1.0;

@Override
public String toString() {

    return super.toString() + "\n"+ account + "\t\t" + deposit + "\t\t" 
        + withdrawAmt +"\t\t" + super.annualEarnings(annualInterest)+ "\t\t" + super.balance ;

}
```

I'm hoping for this type of print out:

```
=======================================
AccNo. Deposit  Withdraw Intr.  NewBal
=======================================
101    200.00   0.00    10.00  1210.00
```

Where the initial simple interest on $1000 annually is $10 aka 10.00 (Intr.) and the rest is simply a $200 deposit added to that $1000 initial with the $10 interest for a NewBal.

Comment: Can you mention , what is the actual output / error that you are seeing, also a full structure of the class would help

Comment: @AkashYadav just added the whole lot - thanks mate!

Comment: still needs a lot to get it working.  please have  a look on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: @AmrElAdawy I appreciate your insight but no need to be passive aggressive with me - I'm here to learn. Originally it was an MWE but you'll notice the comment above you.

Comment: Sure I am not trying to be aggressive by any mean. I am trying to give you hints for not getting down voted. I had tried the code above but had a lot of errors for missing parts. As a good hint, try to put that code in a new project and see how it looks like. I am trying to help. But you have to support as well. Good luck

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Are you getting a compile error, or does the output not match what you expected? Please include the actual error/output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something that does not make any sense to me. In the parent class, the method that calculates the annual earning is taking a variable called  `interest` but then it is totally discarded  and the local variable `interestRate` is used instead.

```
public double annualEarnings (double interest) {

  return this.interest =  1000 * setInterestRate(interestRate);
}
```

I think it should be

```
    public double annualEarnings (double interest) {

      return this.interest =  1000 * setInterestRate(interest);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your note. I tried this and it changed it all - works well now. The devils in the details as they say. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked. Please feel free to ask for anything.